# Auto-enter en TextBox - WinForms

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Verán en mi proyecto ocupo que el programa al momento en que se registre un código de barras se de "**auto-enter**" el `TextBox` y hasta ahora solo eh aprendido con la sintaxis de abajo y me gustaria saber si hay alguna forma de que el textbox de un "**auto-enter**" cuando llegue a cierto numero de caracteres. Gracias.

```
private void TextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.KeyCode==Keys.Enter)
        {
            label1.Text = textBox1.Text;
        }
    }
```

Comment: usa el evento change del textbox

Comment: como sería la sintaxis para el cambio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si es por la lectura de `codigo de barra` esa accion se configura en el lector, para que al final de la lectura agregue un caracter como ser el enter.

El textbox no da ningun enter, solo lo detecta, el que ingresa esa key es el lector. Revisa la configuracion del lector ya que estos proporcionan esta funcionalidad que se puede definir.

Esto cambia segun el modelo del lector, por ejemplo si fuera uno marca `zebra`

[How Do I Enable an Enter Key / Carriage Return Line Feed Suffix after each Scan?](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/knowledge-articles/how-do-i-enable-an-enter-key-carriage-return-line-feed-suffix-after-each-scan.html)

pero esto cambia segun el fabricante